# Is dereferencing illegal without referencing?

Tags: c, pointers

I tried storing a value in an uninitialized pointer using the following code but got segmentation fault (core dumped error ).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   const int a=9;
int *p=&a;
scanf("%d",p+1);
printf("%d %d",*p,*(p+1));

return 0;
}
```

please explain why? Noob here

Comment: There is no uninitialized pointer here. The only pointer is `p` which is well initialized to point to `a`. But you access illegal memory as `p+1` does no point into the same data objec as `p`

Comment: Even if you don't go out of bounds and have undefined behavior because of that, you will still have undefined behavior as you try to write to a constant object. Two wrongs don't make a right, and undefined behavior is still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried storing a value in an uninitialized pointer

This is an initialized pointer: `int *p=&a;`

However, you cannot assign a `const int*` to an `int*` in C, it is invalid code and will not compile cleanly.

> `scanf("%d",p+1);`

The code `p+1` points out of bounds of the allocated variable. You tell `scanf` it's ok to store something at an address where no memory is allocated. This is undefined behavior and may crash.

> *(p+1)

Here you de-reference the pointer, again one item out of bounds. This is not allowed - it is undefined behavior and could cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in

```
 scanf("%d",p+1);
```

you are not allowed to access the memory location as `p+1`, it's outside the legally accessible memory by your program, in other words, invalid memory location. Attempt to access (read/write) invalid memory location invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Lundin I think it's used as argument to scanf, so it's not printing.

Comment: what comes under invalid memory location? And is there any relation b/w dangling ptrs and invalid memory location ?

Comment: Aah right, never mind. My brain was thinking printf :)